# Hit testing bound item in ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, hittest

I have an `ItemsControl` bound to a list, `MyItems`, with objects of `SomeType`. When I click on my UI elements (i.e. ellipses), I want to get hold of the `SomeType` object.

This does **NOT** work:

```
public HitTestResultBehavior SomeTypeHitCallback(HitTestResult result)
{
    if (result.VisualHit is Ellipse)
    {
        var ellipse = result.VisualHit as Ellipse;

        // Does not work...
        object item = itemsSource.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(ellipse);
        // item now equals DependencyProperty.UnsetValue

        // Here I want to change the property of the object
        // associated with the Ellipse...
        var o = item as SomeType;
        o.IsSelected = !o.IsSelected;

        return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
    }

    return HitTestResultBehavior.Stop;
}

private void Canvas_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var pt = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);
    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(
        (UIElement)sender,
        null,
        new HitTestResultCallback(SomeTypeHitCallback),
        new PointHitTestParameters(pt));
}
```

Here's the XAML:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsSource" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <Canvas ClipToBounds="True" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Ellipse x:Name="item" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

How can I find the `SomeType` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itemsSource.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer` will only work if you pass `Item Container`, but not visual elements of it. So you need to find `ContentPresenter` that contains the Ellipse, and pass that as argument to `ItemFromContainer` method. Since `ItemsContainer` for `ItemsControl` is `ContentPresenter`.

One way I see, is to go up by parents from `VisualHit`, until you find `ContentPresenter`, and call `ItemFromContainer` for that item. Try this, it should work. But the problem here might be that ContentPresenter may exist inside the template of ItemsContainer, and you will get null again. Definitely by chaning `ItemsControl` to `ListBox` will make easier to find `ListBoxItem`, but you will have to re-style it and remove additional features you don't require.

Also try to check `Ellipse.DataContext`, I could be exactly what you want

Comment: Would it be a good solution to actually tag the Ellipse with the object? `Tag="{Binding}"` That also works, but I don't know if it's better or worse than your solution.

Comment: Did you try to check DataContext? it should contains element already, if not, I would better bind DataContext instead of Tag. Id this works, it is better than tag and first solution I suggest.